# Type hint for an argument that is an attribute of a class

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I work on a legacy codebase where some constants are encapsulated in a class:

```
class Fields:
    FIELD_1 = 'field 1 name'
```

This class is often use like:

```
some_dict[Fields.FIELD_1]
```

Now I would like to type hint a function operating on this class:

```
def use_field(field: Fields):
    field.startswith('a') # Pylance error: Cannot access member "startswith" for type "Fields"   Member "startswith" is unknown
```

I would like to properly type hint `fields` argument of `use_fields` function.
Currently Pylance will complain as follows:

> Cannot access member "startswith" for type "Fields"   Member
> "startswith" is unknown

I understand why is that - my function expects an instance of `Fields` class at the moment.
But can the type hint be adjusted somehow, possibly without refactoring the `Fields` class into a `Literal` type for example?

Comment: What is `field` supposed to be exactly? *One of the attributes of the class `Fields`*?

Comment: Couldn't the class `Fields` be a `Enum` class? In Python 3.11 even a `StrEnum` class

Comment: @deceze: That is a good question and I guess the root of the problem. I would say "any user-defined class attribute that is also a string` if that makes sense. So there is implicit agreement that the attribute will be a string

Comment: The `use_field` function expects a `Fields` class object. And `Fields` class has `FIELD_1` variable. You have to point exact class variable instead class itself. 
ex.:  `field.FIELD_1.startswith('a')`
or you can add `__str__` function in your `Fields` class

Comment: @JorgeLuis: I thought so as well, but surprisingly changing to `class Fields(Enum)` does not make the error go away.

Comment: Have you also tried `class Fields(str, Enum)`?

Comment: @JorgeLuis: I need to refine my comment. Yes, changing to Enum will work but this also requires changing to `field.value.startswith`. Given the usage of this class and the size of our codebase, a lot of adjustments would need to be made. That is why I am looking to tweak what I already have instead.

Comment: @Shekhrox: Thanks, those are all valid points. The thing is, however, that the function is generic: I don't know what field exactly it will be operating on, instead I want it accept any user-defined field on the `Fields` class.

Comment: If `Fields` inherits from `str` and `Enum`, you can use the values as strings without explicitly accessing their value. It is also true with your dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Type annotations are only for type checking; you can't say "check if passed argument is a field of some class."

Instead, use `enum.Enum`, which turns your class attributes into instances of that class.